# Illegal modifier error for action class

Tags: java, swing

I have been given code to implement a save action, however when I put the code in I got an error:

Illegal modifier for the class saveAction; only abstract or final is permitted.

Code:

```
protected void initialiseActions(){
    // TODO: initalise your actions here 
    public class SaveAction extends AbstractAction{
           public SaveAction(String text, ImageIcon icon, String desc, Integer mnemonic){
               super(text, icon);
               putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, desc);
               putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
           }

               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                   // Just print out a message for now.
                   System.out.println("Save");
           }
      } 

    Action saveAction = new SaveAction("Save", new ImageIcon("img/save.png"), "Save the image",
             KeyEvent.VK_S);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a `public` local class. Remove the `public` identifier.

```
protected void initialiseActions(){
    // TODO: initalise your actions here 
    class SaveAction extends AbstractAction{
           public SaveAction(String text, ImageIcon icon, String desc, Integer mnemonic){
               super(text, icon);
               putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, desc);
               putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
           }

               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                   // Just print out a message for now.
                   System.out.println("Save");
           }
      } 

    Action saveAction = new SaveAction("Save", new ImageIcon("img/save.png"), "Save the image",
             KeyEvent.VK_S);
}
```

This is specified in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3)

> It is a compile-time error if a local class declaration contains any
>   of the access modifiers public, protected, or private (§6.6), or the
>   modifier static (§8.1.1).

Comment: Then I get another error saying "the serialised class saveAction does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long"

Comment: @user1902535 That is a simple warning.

Comment: Also when I try to use an instance of the saveAction class, I get another error saying "saveAction cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: @user1902535 It seems like you need to go through some more Java tutorials. Your variable `saveAction` is declared in the method `initialiseActions`. As such that is its scope. You cannot access it from outside this method.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a class inside a method, which severely limits the usefulness of the class. Either move it into its own file or simply outside any other methods in the class you're talking about here, and using it will be much more convenient.